# How to release memory from UIViewController after popping naviagtion

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

In my app, I am jumping navigation a bit, here is a rough outline of what my navigation does

Login -> Main Screen -> Settings

From settings, I want a logout that goes back to the login page.  I do this like this:

```
UIViewController* requireController = [[[self navigationController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[[self navigationController] popToViewController:requireController animated:YES];
```

This does return me to the login page.  However, I would like to release some things in the Main Screen, for example I have a timer that runs a task every 10 seconds, which continues to run (I can see it in the logs).  viewDidUnload obviously no longer gets called as of iOS6.  viewDidDisapear also is not quite right because that will also get called when going *into* settings.

What should I do here to get rid of some tasks in my main view controller?

Comment: You can probably send a NSNotification using NSNotificationCenter, observe that notification, then tell your MainScreen controller to stop the timer when it does receive the notification.

Comment: how about using -(void)dealloc of main screen view controller?

Comment: All good answers, I ended up going with dealloc, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method to directly jump to the root view controller, in your case the Login controller. If you are not retaining the Main Screen or Settings controllers anywhere in your code, then moving to root view controller will invoke the `dealloc` method on the view controllers getting removed from navigation stack.

You can override the `dealloc` in your main screen controller and release the resources. Remember, if you are using ARC do not make a call to `[super dealloc]` as it will give error. But if you are managing memory manually make sure you add the call at the end of `dealloc`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Set up a protocol on your logout view controller. Before you pop back to the main, call some method to reset the state of that view controller using the protocol (delegate) you created. On the main VC implement that method. AFTER telling the delegate to do whatever, then pop the login VC.

Here are the basics of this pattern.
http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Answer (score 1):

I would either use `NSNotificationCenter` or use the `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` method of `UIViewController`.